# Automount and access to USB memory

Tags: windows, users

Windows 10 Home

i struggle with one problem. im trying to prevent new plugged usb memory to be visible and also i want to this memory be inaccessible to ordinary user, only admin would be able to read and write to this memory.

I tried everything from this:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-auto-mounting-of-drives-disks-volumes-in-windows

and many others.

And it didnt work at all, new connected

I rebooted computer after any change i did.

Any ideas guys?

Please help :)

Comment: In my limited testing, the article you linked to, works.  What are you trying to prevent exactly, the mounting of the volume itself, or it appearing in FIle Explorer?

Comment: Yes it keeps appearing in file explorer and i have still access to it just like i wouldnt do nothing to change it but regedit and automount in diskpart show that it is disabled. Maybe it doesnt work on Home Edition? i dont know ;/

Comment: The only method I know to hide a drive from appearing in File Explorer is a group policy, which means it wouldn't be applicable to Windows 10 Home, you could write a script that simply unassigns the drive letter from the volume.  Have you tried that?

Comment: 1. I tried do that manualy and it works cuz i know wchich volume has assigned letter what if someone plugin multiple usb memory, how to do that automaticly? 2. And I want you ask as well on which windows edition did you test my article wchich i followed? 3. I know that gpedit.msc is not default avallible on windows home bu i found code wchich you can execute to get access to gpedit, but im not sure is it legal and if its gonna work  properly i mean if functions are gonna work or they will be only appear, but wont work